# сложение двух массивов полученых из 2 файлов

Tags: android, android-file

есть 2 кнопки по нажатию на которые читаю и обрабатываю файлы, на каждую кнопку свой файл. Для чтения и обработки на 2 кнопки, 1 метод для чтения и 1 метод для формирования массива. После чтения двух файлов нужно сложить 2 полученных массива, но метод сложения вызывается в  методе формирования массива, а это происходит 2 раза поэтому массивы не складываются как решить эту проблему

```
    private static String TAG = "myLog";
    final String DIR_SD = "MyFiles";
    final String FILENAME1 = "Appeals.txt";
    final String FILENAME2 = "PKK.txt";
    ArrayList <String> list;
    private String [] otv;
    private ArrayList <String> AppealsMass;
    private ArrayList <String> PkkMass;
    private int appealSiz;
    private int pkkSiz;

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        Button btn_open = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_open);

        btn_open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (hasPermissions()){
                    String name = "Appeals";
                    readFileSD(FILENAME1, name);
                   // Log.d(TAG, "доступ получен");

                }
                else {
                    //our app doesn't have permissions, So i m requesting permissions.
                    requestPermissionWithRationale();
                   // Log.d(TAG, "доступ не получен");
                }
            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (hasPermissions()){
                    String name = "PKK";
                    readFileSD(FILENAME2, name);
                    //Log.d(TAG, "доступ получен");

                }
                else {
                    //our app doesn't have permissions, So i m requesting permissions.
                    requestPermissionWithRationale();
                   // Log.d(TAG, "доступ не получен");
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private boolean hasPermissions(){
        int res = 0;
        //string array of permissions,
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        for (String perms : permissions){
            res = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(perms);
            if (!(res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void requestPerms(){
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            requestPermissions(permissions,PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        boolean allowed = true;

        switch (requestCode){
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:

                for (int res : grantResults){
                    // if user granted all permissions.
                    allowed = allowed && (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                }

                break;
            default:
                // if user not granted permissions.
                allowed = false;
                break;
        }

        if (allowed){
            //user granted all permissions we can perform our task.
          //  makeFolder();
           // btnCheckUsbDevClick();
        }
        else {
            // we will give warning to user that they haven't granted permissions.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Storage Permissions denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    showNoStoragePermissionSnackbar();
                }
            }
        }

    }



    public void showNoStoragePermissionSnackbar() {
        Snackbar.make(MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.activity_view), "Storage permission isn't granted" , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("SETTINGS", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        openApplicationSettings();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Open Permissions and grant the Storage permission",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    public void openApplicationSettings() {
        Intent appSettingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(appSettingsIntent, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
          //  makeFolder();
            //btnCheckUsbDevClick();
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    public void requestPermissionWithRationale() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            final String message = "Storage permission is needed to show files count";
            Snackbar.make(MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.activity_view), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("GRANT", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPerms();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {
            requestPerms();
        }
    }

    void writeFileSD(String file, String type) {
        // проверяем доступность SD
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SD-карта не доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
            return;
        }
        // получаем путь к SD
        File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // добавляем свой каталог к пути
        sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR_SD);
        // создаем каталог
        sdPath.mkdirs();
        // формируем объект File, который содержит путь к файлу
        File sdFile = new File(sdPath, file);
        try {
            // открываем поток для записи
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sdFile));
            // пишем данные
            bw.write("Содержимое файла на SD");
            // закрываем поток
            bw.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "Файл записан на SD: " + sdFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void readFileSD(String file, String type) {
        // проверяем доступность SD
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SD-карта не доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
            return;
        }
        // получаем путь к SD
        File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // добавляем свой каталог к пути
        sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR_SD);
        // формируем объект File, который содержит путь к файлу

        if(file == FILENAME1){
            TextView Appeals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_Appeals);
            Appeals.setText(String.valueOf(sdPath) + "/" + type + ".txt");
        }else {
            TextView PKK = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_PKK);
            PKK.setText(String.valueOf(sdPath) + "/" + type + ".txt");
        }
        File sdFile = new File(sdPath, file);
        try {
            // открываем поток для чтения
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sdFile));
            String str = "";
            // читаем содержимое
             list = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {

             //   Log.d(TAG, str);
                list.add(str);
            }
          //  Log.d(TAG, "Прочитали : " +  type);

            fds(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void fds (String name){
        int siz = list.size();
        otv = new String[siz];
        for(int i =0; i<siz; i++){
            String [] fd = list.get(i).split("\t");
            if(fd.length >= 2){
                String [] ds = fd[1].split(";");
               // Log.d(TAG, ds[0]+i);
              //  al.add(ds[0]);
                otv [i] = ds[0];
            }else {
               // Log.d(TAG, fd[0]);
             //   al.add(fd[0]);
            }
        }

        ArrayList <String> mass = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> wordToCount = new HashMap<>();
        for (String word : otv)
        {
            if (!wordToCount.containsKey(word))
            {
                wordToCount.put(word, 0);
            }
            wordToCount.put(word, wordToCount.get(word) + 1);
        }
        for (String word : wordToCount.keySet())
        {
            mass.add(word + ":" + wordToCount.get(word));
        }

        int size = mass.size();
        AppealsMass = new ArrayList<>();
        PkkMass = new ArrayList<>();

        if(name == FILENAME2){
            TextView PKK_size = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pkk_size);
            PKK_size.setText(String.valueOf(siz));
            pkkSiz = siz;
            for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
                PkkMass.add(mass.get(i));
            }
        }else {
            TextView Appeals_size = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appeals_size);
            Appeals_size.setText(String.valueOf(siz));
            appealSiz = siz;
            for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
                AppealsMass.add(mass.get(i));
            }
        }

        TextView documents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.documents_size);
        documents.setText(String.valueOf(pkkSiz+appealSiz));

        table_output();
    }

    public void table_output() {
        int siz = AppealsMass.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++){
          // Log.d(TAG, "ответственные Appeals : " + AppealsMass.get(i));
        }

        int siz2 = PkkMass.size();
        for(int j = 0; j<siz2; j++){
            //Log.d(TAG, "ответственные PKK : " + PkkMass.get(j));
        }

        ArrayList <String> listAB = (ArrayList<String>) ListUtils.union(PkkMass, AppealsMass);
        int siz3 = listAB.size();
        for(int k = 0; k<siz3;k++){
            Log.d(TAG, "Общий массив : " + listAB.get(k));
        }
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(listAB.size()));

    }
}
```

Comment: На твоем месте я бы заюзал `RX`.
Обернул бы метод чтения из файла в `Observable` и дернул бы оператором `CombineLatest`. В `subscribe` получил бы два массива. А сложить их это уже пустяки

Comment: к сожалению пока что с RX не знаком